# Bash for loop to run commands from a text file

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, for-loop

I’m trying to write a `for` loop that looks at a list of hosts in a text file then runs a series of commands from another text file named with the IP of the host and the file `extension.txt`

For example in the `hosts.txt` file I would have the following hosts defined:

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.3.1
192.168.2.197
```

Etc..

In another directory I would have files named as follows with a different set of commands that I wanted to run on each host:

```
192.168.1.1.txt 192.168.3.1.txt 192.168.2.197.txt
```

So if host `192.168.1.1` exists in `hosts.txt`, it runs the commands in `192.168.1.1.txt` against that host. What would be the easiest vehicle in order to get this accomplished if it isn't in the `for` loop?

Comment: If those files are running commands id remove the `.txt` as it may cause confusion. Add something more meaningful like `.sh`

Comment: Example of what `192.168.1.1.txt` would have?

Comment: It would be executing commands on a cisco device and I would be removing SNMP contexts... For example..."no snmp-server group NORMAL v3 priv context vlan-24". The reason they would be different commands for each device is because each device has a different set of vlans applied to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while read file; do
    bash ./files/$file.txt
    # or source ./files/$file.txt, as necessary
done < hosts.txt
```

Comment: +1, Missed that in my answer, I am feeling like a fool.

Comment: @chepner Deleted my post as yours is practically exactly the same except for the sh and it is pointless having duplicate posts clogging the page.

Comment: +1, but I suggest invoking `bash` rather than `sh`, given that the question is tagged `bash` (and, specifically, on Ubuntu, `sh` is `dash`, not `bash`).

Comment: True; I'll change from `.` to `source` as well. May as well take advantage of the readable synonym since we're using `bash`.

Comment: Since the value of `file` is simply an IP address, you should should be able to run `ssh $file` just fine.

Comment: So if I wanted to ssh before I ran the commands all I would have to do is add `sshpass 'password' ssh username@$file` above the bash statement right? @chepner

Comment: Yes, but are you intending to run the `bash` script locally *after* `ssh` exits, or do you want to use `ssh` to execute the `bash` script on the remote host?

Comment: @chapner I would like to use the script to execute the commands in the .txt file on the remote host. The remote host is a Cisco device so it doesn't take conventional linux commands.

Answer (score 0):

```
while read file; do    
bash /path/${file}.txt
done < hosts.txt
```

I guess this should do it for you

Changed Answer, after learning from comment number 2 on this answer.
Which is primarily the same answer provided below.

Comment: if more than one command and each line contains one command, then we can run another for loop. OR replace `\n`  with `;` and execute this script only.

Comment: -1 This is a bad way to iterate over a file, and you are attempting to reimplement the `source` command.

Comment: @chepner I have been using it, not saying your wrongly downvoted, but please explain why its bad way to iterate over file content, any link would do.

Comment: @chepner keeping this post only because expecting explanation from you.

Comment: `$(cat host.txt)` is subject to word splitting, so any line that contains whitespace would be treated as multiple items to iterate over, rather than as a single item.

Answer (score 0):

Using `xargs` is probably easiest here:

```
xargs -I % bash "./scripts/%.txt" < hosts.txt
```

- `-I %` ensures that the specified command is invoked for each input line (line in `hosts.txt`), with the line substituted for the `%` character (as a single argument).
- `./scripts` is assumed to be the directory hosting the scripts to invoke.